# Stream Analytics - Cannot edit the Date format input pattern?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics

I cannot seem to change the Date or Time Format patterns and I am unsure why.

[image]

The service is stopped.

Comment: Nowadays, you can customize date format for your path: [Custom DateTime path patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-custom-path-patterns-blob-storage-output#custom-datetime-path-patterns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot seem to change the Date or Time Format patterns and I am unsure why.

The file path used to write your blobs within the specified container. Within the path, you may choose to use one or more instances of the following 2 variables to specify the frequency that blobs are written:{date}, {time}. If the **date token** and **time token** are not used in the prefix path, we could not specify Date Format and Time Format properties. As we can see, if we specify Path pattern like cluster1/logs/{date}/{time}, it will enable us to select **Date Format** and **Time Format**. For more information about property names and their description for creating a blob output, you could read [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-define-outputs/#blob-storage).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have {date} and {time} in the path pattern? They are necessary to allow you to specify date and time format.

Thanks,
Kati Iceva